# How to get the dom's height when it is loaded in vue?

Tags: vue.js

```
<div class="avator">
    <div class="avator-image"><img src="user1.png" /></div>
    <div class="label">user1</div>
</div>

mounted:function(){
    this.nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(this.$el.height);
    });
```

it gives the dom's height of undisplayed img.

if the img displayed it not this height.
how to get the right height?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the image to load before the height will be available:

```vue
<div class="avator">
  <div class="avator-image"><img src="user1.png" @load="onLoad"></div>
  <div class="label">user1</div>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  onLoad() {
    console.log(this.$el.clientHeight)
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is more imgs then ?

Comment: You have to do it for each image, or encapsulate it in a component.